# Efficiently sample all arrays in ndarray using scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, multidimensional-array

I have a 3D stack of masked arrays.  I'd like to sample all arrays in the stack at the same fixed locations.

```
stack.ma_stack.shape
```

(1461, 390, 327)

```
#Indices to be sampled
x = np.array([ 117.38670304,  119.1220485 ])
y = np.array([ 209.98120554,  210.37202372])
```

The following is very efficient, but only works for integer indices:

```
x_int = np.rint(x).astype(int)
y_int = np.rint(y).astype(int)
samp = stack.ma_stack[:,y_int,x_int]
samp.shape
```

(1461, 2)

I'm trying to implement the scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates interpolated sampling for float indices, but I can't seem to figure out how to format the coordinates properly.

Most examples use map_coordinates to sample a single array, and the following works for a single array from the stack:

```
map_coord = np.array([[y,], [x,]])
samp = scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates(stack.ma_stack[0], map_coord, order=1)
samp.shape
```

(1, 2)

I can loop through each array in the stack, but I know there is a simple indexing trick that will sample the entire stack in a single call.  I read about mgrid, and did some experimentation, but couldn't find the right solution (I'm still learning advanced indexing).  I know somebody out there will know the answer right away.  Thanks.

On a related note: Anybody know how to do this for masked arrays without replacing missing data with fill_value or np.nan?  The ndimage interpolation doesn't play nicely with masked arrays:

https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1682

Answer (score 1):

There must be a way to get it to broadcast automatically... in the meantime, you can force the broadcasting with `np.arange(...)` to get one point from each 2d array in the stack:

```
map_coords = np.broadcast_arrays(np.arange(stack.ma_stack.shape[0])[:, None], y, x)
samp = ndimage.map_coordinates(stack.ma_stack, map_coords, order=1)
```

This is inefficient though, because the "broadcasting" is done in advance (and presumably copies all that data), but it's still quite a bit faster than the loop:

```
In [88]: a = np.random.rand(1461, 390, 327)

In [89]: x = np.array([ 117.38670304,  119.1220485 ])

In [90]: y = np.array([ 209.98120554,  210.37202372])

In [107]: %%timeit
   .....: map_coord = np.array([[y,], [x,]])
   .....: np.concatenate([ndimage.map_coordinates(ai, map_coord, order=1) for ai in a])
   .....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 33.1 ms per loop

In [108]: %%timeit
   .....: map_coords = np.broadcast_arrays(np.arange(a.shape[0])[:, None], y, x)
   .....: ndimage.map_coordinates(a, map_coords, order=1)
   .....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 4.67 ms per loop

In [109]: samp_OP = np.concatenate([ndimage.map_coordinates(ai, map_coord, order=1) for ai in a])

In [110]: samp_chan = ndimage.map_coordinates(a, map_coords, order=1)

In [111]: np.allclose(samp_chan, samp_OP)
Out[111]: True
```

Comment: Thanks @askewchan.  This does the trick.  I'll leave it open for now to see if any other ideas pop up.